# Date changed after serialize Object to String with Jackson Json

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I am litte bit confused. I need to serialize an Object to a json String. I use `Jackson` as library.

My Pojo Class `Stage` has an attribute `fromDate` and its an `util.date`.

```
public class Stage {

@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd.MM.yyyy", timezone="UTC+1")
private Date fromDate;
...
```

Before serialization the fromDate has this value: `Wed May 11 00:00:00 CEST 2016`.

My serialize method looks like this:

```
 public static String serialize(Stages stages) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String s = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(stages);
        return s;
    }
```

But after serialize my Object the dateFrom in the json String hast this value:
 `..."fromDate":"10.05.2016"...` . So the Date is wrong.

I used the pattern of `@JsonFormat` and tried it also with the `ObjectMapper` configuration.

```
public static String serialize(Stages stages) throws JsonProcessingException {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(Util.SDF_dd_mm_yyyy);
    objectMapper.setDateFormat(dateFormat);
    dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC+1"));
    String s = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(stages);
    return s;
}
```

But the date is not my expected one: `..."fromDate":"11.05.2016"...`

What do I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is just another timezone issue. The serialized date looks like it's in UTC (?), so it's actually correct that you're seeing 10.05, cause 2016-11-05 00:00 UTC+1 is really 2016-10-05 23:00 UTC..

You should probably try adapting the code where you're reading this serialized value to take into account what timezone the date has been serialized in.

Comment: I looked up in which timezone the date came and it was `CET`. Change the timezone to `timezone="CET"` and it worked. Thanks.